# MySQL Union on Dissimilar Fields without Dummy Columns

Tags: mysql, join, field, union

So lets say I have 2 or more tables consisting of dissimilar columns in which a shared key (id) is not necessarily present :

```
Alpha:  
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| id | paula | randy | simon |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     8 |     7 |     2 |
|  2 |     9 |     6 |     2 |
|  3 |    10 |     5 |     2 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+

Beta:
+----+---------+-----+------------+------+
| id | is_nice | sex |        dob | gift |
+----+---------+-----+------------+------+
|  2 |       1 |   F | 1990-05-25 | iPod |
|  3 |       0 |   M | 1990-05-25 | coal |
+----+---------+-----+------------+------+

Gamma:
+----+---------+--------+
| id | is_tall | is_fat |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
| 99 |       0 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

The desired effect is to mash the tables together on id inserting NULLs where data is not available:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-----+------------+------+---------+--------+
| id | paula | randy | simon | is_nice | sex |        dob | gift | is_tall | is_fat |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-----+------------+------+---------+--------+
|  1 |     8 |     7 |     2 |         |     |            |      |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |     9 |     6 |     2 |       1 |   F | 1990-05-25 | iPod |         |        |
|  3 |    10 |     5 |     2 |       0 |   M | 1990-05-25 | coal |       1 |      1 |
| 99 |       |       |       |         |     |            |      |       0 |      0 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-----+------------+------+---------+--------+
```

I can use NULL 'dummy' columns and UNION ([MySql SELECT union for different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns)) but that seems like a royal pain if the number of tables is great. I'd like to think there is a JOIN method I can use to accomplish this, but I need some help to figure this out.

This works:

```
SELECT `id`, `paula`, `randy`, ..., NULL AS `is_nice`, ... FROM `Alpha`
UNION SELECT `id`, NULL AS `paula`, ..., FROM `Beta`
UNION SELECT `id`, NULL AS `paula`, ..., `is_fat` FROM `Gamma` ;
```

but it sure feels like the **wrong** way to do it. How can I get the same results without having to edit lines and lines of SQL inserting NULL AS `whatever` all over the place whenever I want to tack on additional tables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, your query would not work like that. You'd get 7 rows in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    allid.id
  , a.paula, a.randy a.simon
  , b. ...
  , c. ... 
FROM
        ( SELECT id
          FROM Alpha
        UNION 
          SELECT id
          FROM Beta
        UNION 
          SELECT id
          FROM Gamma 
        ) AS allid
    LEFT JOIN
        Alpha AS a
            ON a.id = allid.id
    LEFT JOIN
        Beta AS b
            ON b.id = allid.id
    LEFT JOIN
        Gamma AS g
            ON g.id = allid.id
```

---

If the tables share no other column except the `id`, you could use the simple to write (but easier to break):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
        ( SELECT id
          FROM Alpha
        UNION 
          SELECT id
          FROM Beta
        UNION 
          SELECT id
          FROM Gamma 
        ) AS allid
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN
        Alpha
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN
        Beta 
    NATURAL LEFT JOIN
        Gamma
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LEFT JOIN`s.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

In your example:

```
SELECT id_t.id, a.paula, a.randy, a.simon, b.is_nice, b.sex, b.dob, b.gift, g.is_tall, g.is_fat
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM alpha,beta,gamma) as id_t
LEFT JOIN alpha a ON a.id = id_t.id
LEFT JOIN beta b on b.id = id_t.id
LEFT JOIN gamma g on g.id = id_t.id
```

Comment: OK, but it looks like ypercube might have been first.