# Laravel 4 union generate wrong SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Here is the code:

```
    $f = DB::table("topics")
           ->join("recommends", "topics.id", "=", "recommends.courseid")
           ->where("recommends.re_type", "=", $re_type)
           ->where("recommends.re_location", "=", $re_location)
           ->orderBy("recommends.weigh", "desc");

    $s = DB::table("topics")
           ->orderBy("topics.create_time", "desc");

    $f->union($s)->get();
```

I got a wrong SQL around key word `union`:

```
    select * from `topics` inner join `recommends` 
    on `topics`.`id` = `recommends`.`courseid` 
    where `recommends`.`re_type` = ? 
    and `recommends`.`re_location` = ? 
    order by `recommends`.`weigh` desc 
    union //here!!!!!
    select * from `topics` order by `topics`.`create_time` desc
```

The error info:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1221
>   Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY (SQL: ...)
>   (Bindings: array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 7, ))

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL UNIONs expect the same columns in all statements. Because you're joining another table in `$f`, the columns between the two statements don't match.

See [MySql SELECT union for different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns/7407936#7407936)

In this case, it might be less of a headache to use the PDO object directly.

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

Comment: I don't think so, look at both queries, they are `select * from topics...`, there are no other columns.

Comment: Good thinking, but the `*` isn't table-specific. For instance, `select topics.*` would limit the columns, but as the query is written now, it will grab all columns from both tables.

Comment: You're right! Just tested it and MySQL uses all columns from both tables. FirebirdSQL wouldn't do that. :/

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro it can definitely be a frustrating feature. I drilled myself into avoiding asterisks in queries wherever possible for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Found another problem with your query. You should relocate your first order by clause:

```
->orderBy("recommends.weigh", "desc");
```

It is producing the `order by` you before `union` and MySQL will not accept that.