# SQL how to combine multiple SQL Queries into one output

Tags: sql

I am having troubles combining multiple queries into one output. I am a beginner at SQL and was wondering if anyone can provide me with some feedback on how to get this done.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT [status], [queryno_i] as 'Query ID', [assigned_to_group] as 'Assigned To Group', [issued_date] as 'Issuing Date',
CASE
    WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation]
    ELSE NULL
END AS 'Closing Date'
 FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)


SELECT
CASE
    WHEN [status] = 3 THEN 'CLOSED'
    ELSE 'OPEN'
END AS [State]
 FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)


SELECT
CASE
    WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation_int]-[issued_date_INT]
    ELSE NULL
END AS [TAT]
 FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: You need UNION: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @Mörre can we use union even if there are uneven columns?

Comment: The word `combine` can mean so many different things

Comment: @Mörre but that was for sqllite

Comment: @AshReva See the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309943/unioning-two-tables-with-different-number-of-columns

Comment: @Mörre they have used null value so thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all in one row just put all together

```
SELECT [status], 
      [queryno_i] as 'Query ID', 
      [assigned_to_group] as 'Assigned To Group', 
      [issued_date] as 'Issuing Date',
      CASE WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation] ELSE NULL END AS 'Closing Date',
      CASE WHEN [status] = 3 THEN 'CLOSED' ELSE 'OPEN' END AS [State],
      CASE WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation_int]-[issued_date_INT] ELSE NULL 
            END AS [TAT]
 FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use a UNION clause

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

```
SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT 2
  UNION ALL
SELECT 3
```

However, from looking at your 3 statements, all 3 selects are coming from the same table, so you may be able to just combine and use CASE statements to get your results without using a Union.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL, everything would have to be one result set.  In order for you to return the results of all of these queries, they all would have to have the same columns (and data types).

Would you able to combine everything into one select query?

```
SELECT 
    [status]
    , [queryno_i] as 'Query ID'
    , [assigned_to_group] as 'Assigned To Group'
    , [issued_date] as 'Issuing Date'
    , CASE
        WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation]
        ELSE NULL
        END AS 'Closing Date'
    , NULL AS State
    , NULL AS Tat
    , 1 AS QueryNumber
FROM 
    [tech_query] 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
    CASE
        WHEN [status] = 3 THEN 'CLOSED'
        ELSE 'OPEN'
    END AS [State]
    , NULL
    , 2 AS QueryNumber
FROM 
    [tech_query] 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL
CASE
    WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation_int]-[issued_date_INT]
    ELSE NULL
END AS [TAT]
, 3 AS QueryNumber
FROM 
    [tech_query]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT [status], [queryno_i] as 'Query ID', 
   [assigned_to_group] as 'Assigned To Group', [issued_date] as 'Issuing Date',
CASE
   WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation]
   ELSE NULL
END AS 'Closing Date',

CASE
   WHEN [status] = 3 THEN 'CLOSED'
   ELSE 'OPEN'
END AS [State],

CASE
   WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation_int]-[issued_date_INT]
   ELSE NULL
END AS [TAT]


FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Case statements are inline

```
SELECT 
  [status], 
  [queryno_i] as 'Query ID', 
  [assigned_to_group] as 'Assigned To Group', 
  [issued_date] as 'Issuing Date',
  CASE
      WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation]
      ELSE NULL
  END AS 'Closing Date',
  CASE
    WHEN [status] = 3 THEN 'CLOSED'
    ELSE 'OPEN'
  END AS [State],
  SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN [status] = 3 THEN [mutation_int]-[issued_date_INT]
      ELSE NULL
  END AS [TAT]
  FROM tablename.[tech_query] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Why the nolock?