# SQL UNION result format

Tags: sql, union

Let's say I have the following tables:

**[Table1]**

```
DATE       |  VALUE
-----------|-------
10/10/2014 | 120.33
11/10/2014 | 234.02
12/10/2014 | 124.54
13/10/2014 | 545.67
```

**[Table2]**

```
DATE       |  VALUE
-----------|-------
10/10/2014 | 345.35
11/10/2014 | 211.55
12/10/2014 | 643.90
13/10/2014 | 353.55
```

How can I get the values from both tables formatted like this:

```
DATE       |  table1.VALUE |  table2.VALUE
-----------|---------------|---------------
10/10/2014 | 120.33        | 345.35
11/10/2014 | 234.02        | 211.55
12/10/2014 | 124.54        | 643.90
13/10/2014 | 545.67        | 353.55
```

I was trying to use UNION and add a fake "null" column but the result is one table above the other. ([MySql SELECT union for different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns))

Is this even possible?

Comment: At the simplest level: UNION's *add rows*. JOIN's *add columns*. In this case you want to add columns, so you should JOIN. (Yes, I know there is more to it, but this will get OP started.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "`Date`" is a unique key for both tables simply use a join and not a union ... something like:

```
select t1.Date, t1.value, t2.value
  from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.date=t2.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your dates in your date column are unique, you should be joining the tables on the date column rather than using a union

```
select a.date,a.value,b.value
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.date = b.date
```

The type of join is up to you...