# Merge Two Datasets By Common Key SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two datasets:

skus table:

```
old_product_id  sku
       1        AAA
```

price_tables table

```
old_product_id  option_one  option_two
       1          3 Days    One Color
       1          7 Days    One Color
```

I thought I could merge like this:

```
SELECT old_product_id, null, option_one, option_two
FROM price_tables
GROUP BY old_product_id
UNION ALL
SELECT old_product_id, sku, null, null
FROM skus
GROUP BY old_product_id
```

But I get the following result:

```
old_product_id  NULL option_one  option_two
       1        NULL  3 Days     One Color
       1        AAA    NULL        NULL
```

Expected output:

```
old_product_id  Sku option_one  option_two
       1        AAA   3 Days     One Color
       1        AAA   7 Days     One Color
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql SELECT union for different columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns)

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you intend to receive.  Your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's a duplicate, that question provides a solution, had to add nulls in place of empty columns, thanks

Comment: I've ran into another problem, I will edit question so it's no longer a duplicate

Comment: @JackRobson Add your expected output in your post

Comment: Added expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a union you need a join to get your expected output

```
SELECT 
  s.old_product_id,
  s.sku,
  p.option_one,
  p.option_two 
FROM
  skus s
  JOIN price_tables p USING (old_product_id)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce8c3b/1)

Comment: much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

What about trying simple join?

`SELECT p.old_product_id, s.sku, p.option_one, p.option_two
  FROM price_tables p
 INNER JOIN skus s
    ON s.old_product_id = p.old_product_id`

Comment: much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
SELECT old_product_id, sku, '' As option_two FROM price_tables GROUP BY old_product_id, sku
UNION ALL
SELECT old_product_id, option_one, option_two FROM skus GROUP BY old_product_id, option_one, option_two
```

This will give you appropriate result. Hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately that produced a similar error to my original one. I have updated my question with my progress.